# PHP file from subfolder does not call css

Tags: php

I had to call my `resources/includes/header-test.php` from a subfolder called `subfolder/mypage.php`. That was solved with the following code, but gave me a new problem.

```
<?php include __DIR__.'/../resources/includes/header-test.php'; ?>
```

The folder structure can be seen here:
[image: Folder structure]

The problem is now that the css is not called when I go to `mypage.php`. So how can I call my css, so it is working in the php files there is in the root directory, and in the subfolders?

> testProject/index.php -> css is working
>
> testProject/subfolder/mypage.php -> css is not working

**header-test.php**

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<h1>THIS IS THE HEADER FROM INCLUDE</h1>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'resources/includes/header-test.php' ?>

<body>
    <h2 class="font">THIS IS THE INDEX BODY</h2>
    <p>The css works on this page when I link to the css like this in the header:</p>
    <p>link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" </p>

    <a href="subfolder/mypage.php">MyPage subfolder link</a>

</body>

</html>
```

**mypage.php**

```
<?php include __DIR__.'/../resources/includes/header-test.php'; ?>
<body>
        <h2 class="font">THIS IS THE BODY OF SUBFOLDER/MYPAGE.PHP</h2>
        <p>The css does not work when I link like this in the header</p>
        <p>link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.font {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: go to the root / folder / css file

Comment: Hello Fred. Thank you for the answer. Do you mean like this: `<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` ? Then the css is working on mypage.php, but not on index.php

Comment: looks like since the mypage.php is including the header it's still trying to access like this: css/style.css when it should be ../css/style.css

Comment: No `/var/root/public/folder/file.xxx` as an example. Relative paths tend to cause havoc when using the same file throughout an entire project using the same css file (or any (same) file).

Comment: This is the 5th question in your repertoire describing you don't have any clue how paths work. Perhaps read up on it instead.

Comment: Your problem is that your relative directory changes. so the context of "../" changes every time.

Call it like Fred -ii- said. The absolute URL that will never change.

Comment: Could **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** help, maybe?

Comment: I just tried with this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/style.css"  />` . Shouldn't that work?

Comment: ...have you tried it? ;-)

Comment: Yes tried that, but the css is not called with: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/style.css" />`

Comment: To put it simply, included PHP files act as if they are in the same directory as the parent that included them.

Comment: Xorifelse: That was a really weird question. A person ask for help, because the person is not so good, or did not understand it yet... And you a judging like that. You should be ashamed. The person is probably good at some other things, that you are very bad at.

Comment: @NeKr Try like this`href="<?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/css/style.css"`

Comment: @Julie24 I'm rough on the edges, yes. I didn't learn because my teacher was kind to me. Its called trial and error, and every error he gets ends up on Stackoverflow. Asking for help is one thing, doing actual research first is another.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testProject/css/style.css` - you left out the `testProject` folder here. However, it's hard to say which `style.css` file you want here. From the root public folder or from inside `testProject`? If root, then `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/style.css` *n'est-ce pas*?

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean. I just tried with the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testProject/css/style.css"  />` , but that still does not call any css what so ever. Even it would make sense that it should.

Comment: @NeKr try `href="<?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/css/style.css"` or `href="<?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/testProject/css/style.css"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mihalo. Just tried on localhost but same result.

Comment: We're close probably, maybe... So fiddle around a bit more, and use `var_dump()` to see what path you're actually outputting. Good luck.

Comment: I solved it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/testProject/css/style.css">` But that of course gonna give me problems when I upload til the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with the `css/style.css` path being relative the the file.  You should prefix it with `/` to tell the page to load the asset from the 'root' of the web directory.  In short it should be `/css/style.css` and that will work for both pages.

You should note that the root of the web directory, is different from the file server root.  If you're developing locally and have a file such as index.html that lives in `/path/to/your/website/` and you view it in your browser with `/path/to/your/website/index.html`, it will break the path to the asset.

Comment: Hello Kyle. Thank you for the answer. That was also what i tried from the start. But doing it this way is only gonna work for the mypage.php and not the index.php.

Comment: But I could of course call it like this, that is working: http://localhost:8888/testProject/css/style.css . But not so good when I have to upload through ftp and so on, so the path changes

Comment: Why would the path change when you upload from FTP?

Comment: It just do not make any sense for me. The codeline: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/css/style.css">` is working on the live server, but not on my localhost. When I inspect the code on the live server it works: `http://roulettesuite.com/css/style.css` But when I expect the localhost the css is refered as: `http://localhost:8888/css/style.css` , where the correct would be: `http://localhost:8888/testProject/css/style.css`